# What algorithm is best to group cell of a table?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I have a grid and I need to merge all touching `x` (including diagonals) into groups.

```
-----------------------------------------
| |x|x| | | | |x|x|x|x| | |x|x| |x| | | |
-----------------------------------------
| |x|x|x| | | |x|x|x|x| | |x|x| |x|x| | |
-----------------------------------------
| |x| | | |x| | | |x| | | |x| | |x|x| | |
-----------------------------------------
| | | | |x|x|x| | | | | |x|x| | |x|x| | |
-----------------------------------------
| |x| | | |x| | | |x| | | |x|x| | |x|x| |
-----------------------------------------
|x|x|x| | | | | |x|x|x| | | |x|x| | | |x|
-----------------------------------------
|x|x| | | | | | | |x|x|x| | |x|x| | |x|x|
-----------------------------------------
```

I am sure there is already an existing algorithm I could use. What algorithm should I use for this problem?

---

I tried googling, but I am probably wording the problem wrong and not getting any useful results.

Comment: DFS or any other graph traversing algorithm?

Comment: @fas "Distributed File System" really? Not really sure about that :D

Comment: Depth First Search, sorry for ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

A simple BFS over the grid should solve the problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int grid[5][5];

int mark[5][5];

vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > groups;

void bfs(int row, int col){
    queue<pair<int, int>> q;
    q.push(make_pair(row, col));

    vector<pair<int, int>> group;

    while(q.size() > 0){
        pair<int, int> p = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(mark[p.first][p.second]) continue;
        mark[p.first][p.second] = 1;
        group.push_back(p);

        for(int i = -1; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = -1; j < 2; j++){
                if(0 > p.first + i) continue;
                if(p.first + i >= 5) continue;
                if(0 > p.second + j) continue;
                if(p.second + j >= 5) continue;
                if(mark[p.first + i][p.second + j]) continue;
                if(!grid[p.first + i][p.second + j]) continue;
                q.push(make_pair(p.first + i, p.second + j));
            }
        }
    }
    groups.push_back(group);
}

int main(){
    groups.clear();
    memset(grid, 0, sizeof(grid)); memset(mark, 0, sizeof(mark));
    grid[0][0] = 1; grid[0][1] = 1;
    grid[2][2] = 1; grid[2][3] = 1; grid[3][3] = 1; grid[3][4] = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            if(mark[i][j]) continue;
            if(grid[i][j]) bfs(i, j);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < groups.size(); i++){
        cout<<"group "<<(i + 1)<<": ";
        for(int j = 0; j < groups[i].size(); j++){
            cout<<"("<<groups[i][j].first<<", "<<groups[i][j].second<<") ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Added a working example with a 5x5 grid, where 1 represent `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You could visit all cells and use a counter for connected islands.

```js
function check(array) {

    function test(array, i, j, value) {
        if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
            array[i][j] = value;
            test(array, i - 1, j - 1, value);
            test(array, i - 1, j, value);
            test(array, i - 1, j + 1, value);
            test(array, i + 1, j - 1, value);
            test(array, i + 1, j, value);
            test(array, i + 1, j + 1, value);
            test(array, i, j - 1, value);
            test(array, i, j + 1, value);
            return true;
        }
    }
    var value = 1;

    array.forEach(a => a.forEach((b, i, bb) => bb[i] = -b));
    array.forEach((a, i, aa) => a.forEach((b, j) => test(aa, i, j, value) && value++));
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += array.map(a => a.join(' ')).join('\n');
}

check([' xx    xxxx  xx x   ', ' xxx   xxxx  xx xx  ', ' x   x   x   x  xx  ', '    xxx     xx  xx  ', ' x   x   x   xx  xx ', 'xxx     xxx   xx   x', 'xx       xxx  xx  xx'].map(s => [...s].map(v => +(v !== ' '))));
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```